# Interesting Questions for all MY Stack Exchange sites in one place

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, question-lists, interesting-page

At the moment, I actively participate in Stack Overflow. I would like to be able to participate in others (Project Management for instance). I can do this but I have to watch two "Interesting" lists. Imagine wanting to participate actively in 10 sites. How would you manage?

I think it would be great if, alongside tags, I could also select sites to include questions for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the main [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) page and create a [custom filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/53003/my-filter) (requires login).  You can filter by only those sites that you want to follow, and even further by just the tags you're interested in on those sites.